# Javadoc editor with UI

Tags: java, ide, editor

I'm looking for a Javadoc editor with UI (better if it supports other languages and has some IDE Plugins, better on IntelliJ).

After days, I've only found references to Doxygen, Sphynx and similars, but I don't need a documentation generator.
I just need an intuitive editor to avoid writing @link, html code and so on to document my code because it's a too slow process.

Any ideas?

Comment: What would be a theoretical example of editor functionality that’s faster than writing `{@link FooBar}`?

Comment: Mine was just an example, there is a lot of HTML code to write to make Javadoc more readable.
Like most documentations, you need to provide code example too, and there, some good indentation is required too.

Comment: I would estimate that 98% of the javadoc I’ve written has had no markup other than `{@code}`, `{@link}`, and `<p>`.  Occasionally I have lists (`<ol>`, `<ul>`, `<dl>`) or `<pre>` blocks.  Like most of HTML, these are designed to be easy to write by hand.  If by “good indentation” you mean code formatting, I would put that code in a method temporarily and format it with the IDE.